# Can a non-generic class extend. from a generic class or interface?

Tags: java, generics

I'm relatively new to generics, So I'm not even sure if my question is valid/I'm not asking the right question. I tried Implementing a generic interface on a regular class, but it seems like I have to declare the generic type before implementing the class.

Comment: Yes, you can have `class MyStringList implements List<String>`

Comment: What @ernest_k said or, if the interface is generic, an example might be `class MyThing implements Comparable<Thing>`.

Comment: In case your question is answered, please don't forget about accepting the answer at some point.

Answer (score 2):

When you implement a generic interface, or extend a generic class, you have two choices:

- you keep the new thing generic as well: `MySpecialCallable<V> extends Callable<V>`
- you make it non-generic by extending via a specific type: `MyIntegerCallable extends Callable<Integer>`

Both patterns are legit and have their place in the real world.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer! I have another question if that's alright, I have a method in a generic class that implements a generic interface. The method returns the generic interface, Why do I have to reDeclare the generic type before writing the return type, even though I already declared it in the class header?

Comment: @Faisal If you have another question, then feel free to post it as a new question. Note that your new question doesn't make sense as phrased, since Java doesn't have "headers", and code would help.